# Maven - dependency list and download artifacts

Tags: maven, maven-2, maven-3, maven-plugin

Is it possible to find all dependencies in a maven projects like mvn dependency:tree, save results to file and then use mvn command for download all dependencies from list file in command line?

thanks

Comment: I don't understand the detour via dependency:tree and a file? Why not building the project and all needed dependencies will be downloaded. It would be helpful to know what your actual problem really is and what kind of issue you have?

Comment: Yes, could you please describe what problem you want to solve with your "download the dependencies" approach?

Comment: This is most likely for preseeding a build job without access to the internet

Answer (score 0):

In my experience the various plugins do not get a 100% coverage so the builds will fail.  What worked for me, was to start with an empty .m2/repositories folder, and then do the maven commands you need to do, and then persist the now populated .m2/repositories folder.

I experimented with converting it to a local file repository in the project itself so we could do with offline builds, but this turned out to be too big for our purposes. It might not be that much of an obstacle today.

Unless you have very strict political requirements, the usual pragmatic solution is to have a local repository on your network like nexus or artifactory mirroring maven central which is then accessed as a mirror.